# How to get the attachment full path of an email in java

Tags: java, email

Almost all java examples showing how to send an email set dummy file path. But actually we don't know the path before file selection. I have already known input=file can't get the full path of the file due to security problems. Then how can I get the path as email function must use path?

Here is the part in most examples that would use file path

```
String path = "D:\\jar\\java-json.jar";
String fileName = "java-json.jar";
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(path);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
```

Comment: Are You use java swing?

Comment: Why can't the full path be used?  Are you developing an applet?  If you're not, you probably don't have to worry too much about security.

Comment: Sorry to mention about it, actually I'm running this on a java servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, at last it shows most java email examples on Internet are not useful for web browsers as web browser can't get full path of a file. At last I use the InputStream to get the file and put it into the DataSource. These two lines are the keys:

```
InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(filecontent, "Text/txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) library?
It has features for email attachments, and it has built-in support for java servlet integration.

Comment: Thank you Csuki, I have browsed the link. The example still use a setPath method and put in a path he already knows there is a file in it, but what actually troubles me is that how can I get the full path of the file from web browser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'java-mail-1.4.*.jar' then simply do this...
you use 'JFileChooser' to create file chooser popups, then may be (say) in your actionListner method for a button do the following -

```
 filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

where 'filepath' is a String, and 'fc' is a object to 'JFileChooser' class

Comment: By the way this was the answer if you are looking for path to file via the swing filechooser....